# Harvest Moon Tree of Tranquility - Cherries

Tags: harvest-moon-tree-of-tranquility

My wife is playing Harvest Moon: Tree of Tranquility and can't seem to find any use for the cherries. Do they have any kind of use in the game, or are they just there to frustrate people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/933022-harvest-moon-tree-of-tranquility/faqs/57386), they can be eaten or given as a gift to Angie

Comment: Also according to that guide "cherry trees make the most money, but have no recipes that can be made from their fruit." Thanks for the link.